# Eclipse IDE jst.web version

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I am trying to change jst.web version through eclipse .settings file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core, but when I update my project in maven, previously set version is set again. Is there some other place I can configure that, but in the way it stays after project update?

Here is my pom file:

```
<properties>
        <!-- Can be overriden by Jenkins build parameter -->
        <distribution>${project.artifactId}</distribution>
        
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.8.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springframework.security-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security-version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.11</logback.version>

        <!-- Dates -->
        <jodatime-hibernate.version>1.3</jodatime-hibernate.version>
        <jodatime-jsptags.version>1.1.1</jodatime-jsptags.version>
        <jodatime.version>2.3</jodatime.version>
        <jadira-usertype-core.version>3.1.0.CR8</jadira-usertype-core.version>

        <!-- Webjars -->
        <bootstrap-version>3.1.1</bootstrap-version>
        <jquery-version>2.1.0-2</jquery-version>
        <datatables-version>1.9.4</datatables-version>
        <dandelion.datatables.version>0.9.3</dandelion.datatables.version>
        <select2-version>3.4.6</select2-version>
        <handlebars-version>1.3.0</handlebars-version>
        <momentjs-version>2.6.0-2</momentjs-version>
        <jquery-cookie-version>1.4.1</jquery-cookie-version>

        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>

    </properties>
    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env.SPRINGPROFILE>dev</env.SPRINGPROFILE>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <env.SPRINGPROFILE>prod</env.SPRINGPROFILE>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <env.SPRINGPROFILE>test</env.SPRINGPROFILE>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dandelion -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-servlet2</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${bootstrap-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${jquery-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
            <version>${datatables-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>select2</artifactId>
            <version>${select2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>handlebars</artifactId>
            <version>${handlebars-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>momentjs</artifactId>
            <version>${momentjs-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-cookie</artifactId>
            <version>${jquery-cookie-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>blueimp-file-upload</artifactId>
            <version>9.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache commons-collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Date and Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${jodatime.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${jodatime-hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
            <version>${jodatime-jsptags.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>${jadira-usertype-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- SLF4J - logging api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Interceptor for Commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Interceptor for java.util.logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logback - logging impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
        <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.1</version> 
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- jQuery autocomplete -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jQuery-Autocomplete</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird-jdk17</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${distribution}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/db/*.sql</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <buildNumberPropertyName>buildNumber</buildNumberPropertyName>
                    <scmBranchPropertyName>buildScmBranch</scmBranchPropertyName>
                    <shortRevisionLength>8</shortRevisionLength>
                    <format>{0} {1,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>scmVersion</item>
                        <item>timestamp</item>
                    </items>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <profile>${env.SPRINGPROFILE}</profile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What's your pom file?

Comment: What version are you trying to set, and what does it keep going back to?

Comment: I am trying to set version 2.4 and I am having 3.0